# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=ms_harga[]]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want so separate my number with dot using jquery number divider. it's only works on my static input. when i have input element with array name like "name='ms_harga[]'" (cause i'm use it for dynamic input) it sent me following error

> app.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   input[name=ms_harga[]]

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" id="divide1" class="divide form-control"
                       placeholder="Cashback" name='ms_harga[]' value=""
                       style="margin-right: 3px;">
```

**javascript :**

```
$(".divide").divide({delimiter: '.'});
$(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var content = "<div class='form-group row mt-1 mb-2'><div class='position-relative'><input type='text' id='name' class='divide form-control' placeholder='Terjual' name='ms_jumlah[]' value=''style='margin-left:3px;''></div><div class='position-relative'><input type='text' id='name' class='form-control' placeholder='Cashback' name='ms_harga[]'' value='' style='margin-right:3px;'></div><button class='btn btn-success btn-add' style='margin-left: 5px;' type='button'>+</button></div>";
        $('div#formPencapaian').append(content);
        $(this).removeClass('btn-success btn-add').addClass('btn-danger btn-remove').text('x');

});
```

Comment: can you please share folder structure with you files too. so i can easily understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use https://github.com/tyugaev/jquery-number-divider 
then I think you should modify number-divider.js file.

```
// if input have name
            if (data.name) {
                $this.parent().children("input[name=" + data.name + "]").val(text);
            }
```

to

```
// if input have name
            if (data.name) {
                $this.parent().children("input[name='" + data.name + "']").val(text);
            }
```

I think you need single quotation marks.
Please try it.